# From ruby on rails website/webapp to Phonegap Android app?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cordova

I would like to ask for some advice on this issue I am having. I am working on a website that is made with ruby on rails (along with html.slim, css, angular.js).

I would like to create an Android (and, if possible also iOS/Windows Phone) app to access a part of this website.

The website does nothing more than making some api calls to a server and it's really light, so I think that I don't need to make a native app. I would like to make this app in the fastest and easiest way possible. I thought that I would be able to make convert the site using Phonegap, but this would work if it was made only with html,css and js, not also with ruby on rails. The only thing I need is to store a small string on the device (the website stores a cookie) and then to make a few simple API calls.

Thank you for any advice on this - not so clever - question.

Bye!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe (if you need real simple app for mobile platforms) you should create Android/iOS app with browser object inside app who will be receiving html data from your public website and show it for user. You just need to create mobile layouts in your rails application.

**pros:**

- You can create this app real quickly;
- Easy for update;
- Don't need to update app if something changed in general web application layouts or logic.
- When you create layouts for mobile they will be work for your applications and for mobile devices who doesn't use your app.

**cons:**

- This is not classic application, it just browser inside your app.

It is not a bad solution for start. For most sites, and projects it will be enough.

More information about rails and mobile layouts for rails you can find here:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices

Example how looks like android app with browser (Webview) object:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted

I'm sorry if this is not the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap, Cordova, Ionic, etc. - all the same.  None of them will run your API (aka server side code - PHP, Ruby, .NET) without doing something dramatic.

Easiest approach - write server side services (e.g. REST services) using your favorite server side code - like Ruby, and use JS to securely call into those services.

This fits the PhoneGap/Cordova/Ionic paradigm, and will allow you to build a hybrid app (aka seemingly native app) the quickest.

Just my 2 cents.