# Connect rails app to android one

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, heroku

I have recently finished a rails app and Its is currently hosted in heroku, It has a database setuped and every thing. In the app you can upload users edit them, etc. .Now, I want to create an android aplication that can do the same things.
I have been reading about using rest but I am not shure that is the way. Any other options, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just two option:

1. Create your own API in your rails app:

Manually:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning

Using some gem:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem

or

2. create android app with Webview object for working with you app by internet like browser
   https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted

very similar question:
[From ruby on rails website/webapp to Phonegap Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202019/from-ruby-on-rails-website-webapp-to-phonegap-android-app)